# Is it possible to transfer stock I already own into my Roth IRA without having to sell the stock?

Tags: united-states, stocks, roth-ira, transfer

My cash is already in the stock. Can I just transfer the stock to my Roth IRA?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. A deposit to an IRA must be in cash.
A conversion from traditional IRA to Roth can be "in kind" i.e. As a stock transfer.
Last, any withdrawals can also be in stock or funds.

IRS Publication 590, so important, it's now in 2 sections [Part A](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590a.pdf) and [Part B](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p590b.pdf), addresses IRA issues such as this as well as most others.

By the way - now on page 7 - "Contributions, except for rollover contributions, must be in cash."

Comment: Joe, can you link the relevant publication?

Comment: Sorry, You don't have Pub 590 on your night table? Adding link to my answer.